# Click on specific link in table row

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selector

I'm testing with Selenium Webdriver in Firefox and ideally also in IE8.

Here is my html structure:

```
<table id="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Text1</td>
        <td><a id="assign" href="/assign/1>Assign</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text2</td>
        <td><a id="assign" href="/assign/2>Assign</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text3</td>
        <td><a id="assign" href="/assign/3">Assign</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Basically what I need to do is this:
Click on the assign link on the row that contains `Text1`

So far i came up with the XPATH: `//*[@id='table']//tr/td//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//a` that selects all the assign links.   Changing it to `//*[@id='table']//tr/td[text='Text1']//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//following-sibling::td//a` returns "No matching nodes" from Firebug.

However, I want a CSS selector for this. So, i tried `#table>tbody>tr:contains('Text1')` but Firebug returns "Invalid CSS Selector".

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Perhaps you could use an attribute selector where href is the attribute: [href="/assign/1"]

Comment: @Qaz If I didn't need to check for the text I could simply do #assign.click or something like that, but I need to know which link to click first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the `td` that has preceding `td` sibling tag with `Text1` text, then get the `a` tag:

```
//table[@id="table"]//td[preceding-sibling::td="Text1"]/a[@id="assign"]
```

Comment: `//table[@id="table"]//td` selects my tds.
`//table[@id="table"]//td[preceding-sibling::td="Text1"]` return "No matching nodes" in Firebug.

Comment: @Ciuclpgfmk well, I've tested the xpath before putting an answer on the input you've provided - it works for me..

Comment: @Ciuclpgfmk can you also check this: `//table[@id="table"]//td[normalize-space(preceding-sibling::td/text())="Text1"]`?

Comment: I managed to select the link by using //table[@id='table']//tr//td[contains(text(), 'Text1')]/..//a. Thanks for your help @alecxe!

Comment: @Ciuclpgfmk oh yeah, `contains` can work too. Thanks for sharing. Also, consider accepting the answer if you think it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can find `'tr'` having `'td'` with `text = 'Text1'` and then inside the `'tr'` find `'td'` having text 'Assign'

```
//table[@id='table']//tr[td[.='Text1']]/td[.='Assign']
```

About css selectors, there are no pure css selector for text based search. `'contains'` is not standardized yet, so may not work in your case.